# Encapsulating Directive Attributes on Alpine JS

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I want to learn how Alpine JS "encapsulating directive attributes/reusable attributes" give the same result like using "reusable data" like my code example below, but seems not to be working as I expected.

```
<!--1-->
<h3>Reusable Data</h3>
<div x-data="dropdown">
<button @click="toggle">Open/Close</button>
<div x-show="open">Here I'm</div>
</div>
```

```
<!--2-->
<h3>Reusable Attribute</h3>
<div x-data="drpd-att">
<button x-bind="trigger">Click Me</button>
<div x-bind="dialogue">Hide or Show this sentence.</div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

```
/* Inside app.js file */
document.addEventListener('alpine:init',()=>{
Alpine.data('dropdown',()=>({open: false,

    toggle() {
        this.open = ! this.open
    }
})),
Alpine.data('drpd-att',()=>({
    open: false,

    trigger: {
        ['x-on:click']() {
            this.open = ! this.open
        }
    },
    
    dialogue: {
        ['x-show']() {
            open
        }
    }
}))

})
```

Please help me to find why the second is not working, thanks

I want to learn how Alpine JS "encapsulating directive attributes/reusable attributes" give the same result like using "reusable data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors: the function name cannot contain hyphen, replace it with e.g. underscore. Secondly: at `x-show` you have to return the value you want to use at the directive, in your case: `return this.open`. The fixed component:

```
<div x-data="drpd_att">
  <button x-bind="trigger">Click Me</button>
  <div x-bind="dialogue">Hide or Show this sentence.</div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('drpd_att', () => ({
    open: false,

    trigger: {
      ['x-on:click']() {
        this.open = !this.open
      }
    },

    dialogue: {
      ['x-show']() {
        return this.open
      }
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

Comment: ok I got it thanks, worked here